# java.lang.NullPointerException with context.getSharedPreferences(STORAGE_NAME, 0)

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have created a class for working with `SharedPreferences`. In my `Activity`, I am trying to add an item and get the following error...

```
06-05 17:01:53.950: E/AndroidRuntime(3488): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-05 17:01:53.950: E/AndroidRuntime(3488): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-05 17:01:53.950: E/AndroidRuntime(3488):     at com.xcxcxc.helpers.Prefs.init(Prefs.java:16)
06-05 17:01:53.950: E/AndroidRuntime(3488):     at com.xcxcxc.helpers.Prefs.addStringProperty(Prefs.java:30)
06-05 17:01:53.950: E/AndroidRuntime(3488):     at com.xcxcxc.usersadapter.SplashActivity$1.callback(SplashActivity.java:78)
06-05 17:01:53.950: E/AndroidRuntime(3488):     at com.xcxcxc.usersadapter.SplashActivity$1.callback(SplashActivity.java:1)
```

This is my code for handling the `SharedPreferences`...

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

public class Prefs {

    public static final String STORAGE_NAME = "ApplicationPrefs";

    private static SharedPreferences settings = null;
    private static SharedPreferences.Editor editor = null;
    private static Context context = null;

    public static void init(Context cntxt) {
        context = cntxt;
    }

    private static void init() {
        settings = context.getSharedPreferences(STORAGE_NAME, 0);
        editor = settings.edit();
    }

    /* String values */
    public static void addStringProperty(String name, String value) {
        if (settings == null || editor == null) {
            init();
        }
        editor.putString(name, value);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public static String getStringProperty(String name) {
        if (settings == null || editor == null) {
            init();
        }
        return settings.getString(name, null);
    }
}
```

This is the code I am calling in my `Activity`...

```
Prefs.addStringProperty("client_id", "1JDkv9sdfj8sf63rjs");
```

Comment: your `context` is null so NPE.so call first this `init(Context cntxt)` method and check in your `if(null!=context){}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the Context is null. Set the Context before addStringProperty(..)

```
Prefs.init(getApplicationContext());
Prefs.addStringProperty("client_id", "1JDkv9sdfj8sf63rjs");
```

Answer (score 0):

`context` seems to be **null**. try to call

```
public static void init(Context cntxt)
```

first

Answer (score 0):

```
settings = context.getSharedPreferences(STORAGE_NAME, 0);
```

This statement must be causing the NPE.
How and where are you calling `init(Context cntxt)` method.

Unless the context object is initialized, you will get an `NPE`. Fix it first.

Answer (score 0):

`context` is probably null, this is why you're getting null pointer exception:

```
private static void init() {
    settings = context.getSharedPreferences(STORAGE_NAME, 0);
    editor = settings.edit();
}
```

call `public static void init(Context cntxt)` first or handle the null value:

```
private static void init() {
    if(context != null){
       settings = context.getSharedPreferences(STORAGE_NAME, 0);
       editor = settings.edit();
    }
}
```